# Building NAS adapter

Tags: network, circuit-design, storage

Does anyone have and idea about NAS adapters internal components architecture (what are the components?)  ?
A PDF document with schemes would be great.
I couldn't find such a thing anywhere.
--Thanks in advance--
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At it's heart a NAS adapter is really a small computer with a Network interface and a storage interface such as a USB port or a [E]SATA jack.

If you are looking to get into what that really entails you could look at things like the Raspberry Pi or other small platforms and how they work.